# classes are not listing in Class view(Architecture Explorer) in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, uml

I want to generate UML Class diagram from my existing solution. As per the link 
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx, I have to drag and drop the classes from class view. But if I opened class view in Architecture explorer, the classes are missing.

1 MFC project and 5 Win32 projects present in my solution.
Am I missing anything, while opening the class view?

EDIT: The link says for C# classes. Doesn't this work for C++ code? (My projects are in C++)

Comment: Guessing from what Mickeysoft did in the past to cook its own soups I'd guess you discovered the reason.